# Doing something “on pickup” or “at pickup”

Tags: prepositions

Let's say a driver comes at your place to pick up an item and wants to be paid. Do you arrange to pay at pickup or on pickup?

Comment: I think that either preposition will work, although I personally think that *on* is probably more common.

Comment: It really doesn't matter, but "on pickup" would prolly be more natural.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think it's "on pickup" since the location of the pickup isn't a destination for you. If the driver doing the picking up initiated the question about being paid, they would ask to be paid "at pickup," but you would agree to "pay on pickup" or even "pay upon pickup" if you're controlling that part of the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no *commonly* noted phrase for this type of pickup payment, and either *on* or *at* are grammatical.

However, there is a common phrase associated with *delivery*: [**cash on delivery (COD)**](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/cash-on-delivery-COD.html):

> [BusinessDictionary]
>
> Payment method in which ordered goods are carried to the buyer's place but are handed over only upon full payment. Also called collect on delivery.

Because of the more common association with ***on*** *delivery*, it sounds more natural to me to also hear *payment* ***on*** *pickup*.

---

Note, I am able to find several instances where *cash on pickup* is used:

[**opencart**](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=21295):

> This module will add "Cash on Pickup" to your Payment Method upon checkout.

[**Smoolis**](https://support.smoolis.com/cash-on-pickup-payment/):

> Cash on Pickup it’s a good thing when you have a real store. So your local customer pays cash when he’s picking up the purchased product personally in your store. For both, you and your customer, it’s an advantage because there are no shipping costs, and for your customer it gives the opportunity to inspect the goods and buy some more stuff.

[**Acronym Finder**](https://www.acronymfinder.com/Cash-on-Pickup-(COP).html):

> What does COP stand for?
> COP stands for Cash on Pickup

---

To be fair, a similar search for *cash at pickup* results in similar links, even from, for instance, [opencart](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=21020) itself. (Although it does seem to be used more informally.)

Answer (score 0):

If you imagine the actions of *picking up the package* and *receiving payment for the service* as being sequential, then **on** is the more natural form.

If you imagine these actions as forming a unit, possibly within a larger sequence of events, then **at** may be more appropriate.

For example:

- Your shipped package will be scanned *at pickup*, *at delivery*, and *at intermediate points* where its routing is determined by one of our employees and the package itself can be scanned.
- You can pay *on pickup*, or your customer can pay *on delivery*.
- If your customer is unable to receive the package at the address you specify, the delivery driver will leave a note indicating where the package will be held for customer pickup.  If your customer is paying *on delivery*, the customer pickup location will be limited to places where payment can be accepted.
- Payment *at the customer pickup location* may be made using cash, debit card, or credit card.
- Our insurance coverage on the shipped package ceases *upon your 
  departure* from the customer pickup location with the package physically in your possession.